# Get category id for a custom category and display it in a class

Tags: php, categories, custom-taxonomy, functions

I am having trouble displaying my custom category ID to my li ID. The code I am using below is displaying the post ID of the post category instead of the custom category.

What I am trying to do is assign a ID for each custom category that is assigned to the post. With each category having a different ID I will be able to assign a style to each one. How would I go about assigning a different ID or category ID to my li?

```
 <?php $taxonomy = 'post_tools'; $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :?>
        <ul>
              <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
              <li id="tools-<?php $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
        </ul>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing what you're looking for but you never actually echo the `cat_ID` in the li and there's no reason to assign `$cat->cat_ID` to `$cat_id`.

Additionally, I think you could just as well use something like this to get the category id (or ids) to display the current category(ies) of the current post. (using `$category[0]` will give you the first category)

```
    <ul>

        <?php 

           $category = get_the_category(); 
           foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

              <li id="tools-<?php echo $category[0]->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>

         <?php } ?>
     </ul>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. I figure it out but was unable to post my answer until 8 hours after the post. Your function did work though @leromt